# Laravel query where value equals value in another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make a query with the Query Builder. I am trying to make a `where` close so it select the value that equals to the value stored in another table according to another where clause.

Let me explain myself, I have this table:

```
select negotiation_id, status_id from negotiations_statuses;
+----------------+-----------+
| negotiation_id | status_id |
+----------------+-----------+
|              1 |         1 |
|              2 |         1 |
|              3 |         1 |
|              4 |         1 |
|              5 |         1 |
|              6 |         1 |
+----------------+-----------+
```

And this table:

```
select * from statuses;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | open       |
|  2 | in_process |
|  3 | completed  |
|  4 | rejected   |
+----+------------+
```

I want to select the negotiations that are not `completed` or `rejected`.

This is what I tried:

```
$items = DB::table('negotiations')
            ->join('negotiations_statuses', 'negotiations.id', '=', 'negotiations_statuses.negotiation_id')
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('status_id', '!=', '3')
            ->where('status_id', '!=', '4')
            ->get();
```

It works but I'm obviously cheating because I am using the `status_id` directly. How can I make such nested query?

Comment: Do you want to use a sub query or a nested where query?

Comment: a nested where query

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = DB::table('negotiations')
        ->join('negotiations_statuses', 'negotiations.id', '=','negotiations_statuses.negotiation_id')
        ->whereNotExists(function($query){
             $query->where('status_id', '<>', 3)
                   ->where('status_id', '<>', 4);
        })
        ->get();
```

This query will get all items that are not completed or rejected.

**Note**: This has not been tested.

Comment: it doesn't work: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `status_id` <> ? and `status_id` <> ?)' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `negotiations` inner join `negotiations_statuses` on `negotiations`.`id` = `negotiations_statuses`.`negotiation_id` where `user_id` = 2 and not exists (select * where `status_id` <> 3 and `status_id` <> 4))

Comment: also that's not what I am trying to do, I am trying to compare the name of the status, not the value...

Comment: Okay. Seems easy enough. About the error, could you change <> to != and see if you get the same error?

Comment: yes I get the same error, but I am trying to do something like this `DB::table('negotiations')
    ->join('negotiations_statuses', 'negotiations.id', '=', 'negotiations_statuses.negotiation_id')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereRaw("status_id not in (select statud_id from statuses where name=='completed' or name=='rejected'")
    ->get();` I am getting a syntax error here though

Comment: You need 1 equal sign for your where clauses in the raw query
(name == 'completed' or name == 'rejected')

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `negotiations` inner join `negotiations_statuses` on `negotiations`.`id` = `negotiations_statuses`.`negotiation_id` where `user_id` = 2 and status_id not in (select statud_id from statuses where name='completed' or name='rejected')

Comment: I'm confused. Where is a " in your query? Just a note, statud_id is spelled wrong.

Comment: that was just a typo. I don't know where `''` is in my querey. Look at the generated query:  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `negotiations` inner join `negotiations_statuses` on `negotiations`.`id` = `negotiations_statuses`.`negotiation_id` where `user_id` = 2 and status_id not in (select status_id from statuses where name='completed' or name='rejected')